# How to replace one char with another in filenames

Tags: debian, files, rename

I have a folder with subfolders on a Debian 9 system that has a lot of files with a `?` character in the name. I want to rename then changing the `?` to a `_`.  For example, `A?oranza.txt` -> `A_oranza.txt`.

I tried a lot of commands that I've found on this site without luck.

Comment: Try to run the `detox` command

Comment: I'm assuming it's `ls` that shows the characters as `?`, right? That means that the filenames contain some unprintable character, but probably not the literal character `?`.

Comment: ... In which case setting your locale correctly may make the characters readable

Comment: The folder is a backup of a window machine that was did with deltacopy (rsync for win using cygwin); the hardrive of that machine has died and I want to restore the backup to a new disk. Yes, I see them with ls command and the ? are replacing spechial characters (example: ñ); the problem is that when I copy the folder to an external hard drive  (rsync and cp) that files gives errors and didn't get copied. If I rename them then the files get copied.

Comment: Do you get output from `find /path/to/folder -name '*\?*'`?

Comment: No... Nothing listed

Comment: Then  Kusalananda's assumption is correct. Those are no literal `?` characters, just fallback symbols.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I get the files copied to another hard drive??

Comment: All files or only the `?` files?

Comment: You might be able to identify the special characters in the filenames by using a command something like this: 
`for i in * ; do echo "$i" | xxd ; done`

The `xxd` part of the command will display the filename in hexadecimal and ASCII so that you can identify the special character.

Someone smarter than I could probably tell you how to substitute those characters with an underscore, as you have asked.

Comment: @StephenDaddona I didn´t undersand the output of your command; for example, for a file called "2010 PLANILLA PARA RENDICIONES N? 5 10-12-2010-CORREGIDA.xls" -i get the following output:00000000: 504c 414e 494c 4c41 2050 4152 4120 5245  PLANILLA PARA RE
00000010: 4e44 4943 494f 4e45 5320 4eba 2035 2031  NDICIONES N. 5 1
00000020: 302d 3132 2d32 3031 302d 434f 5252 4547  0-12-2010-CORREG
00000030: 4944 412e 786c 730a                      IDA.xls.

Comment: The xxd command is dumping the filename in hexadecimal.  You would have to examine the output to find the hexadecimal representation of the unprintable character and then find a way to search for and replace that character (instead of a questionmark character.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for the right way to setup again the backup for the windows machine through rsync I found a new solution for my problem. Like @Kusalananda and @HaukeLaging where saying the ? were not really a ?, was a special character that aren't get printed. I make a copy of the folder with `rsync` and the `--iconv=iso-8859-1,utf8` parameter and the resulting folder have the correct symbols or special characters in her name (like ñ or á)

`detox` did a god job too but with `rsync --iconv=iso-8859-1,utf8` now I have the correct filenames.
Thanks to everyone thats post an answer!!

Answer (score 2):

After reading again your question/answer/comments, you really should give a try to `detox`.

Because, trying to figure out what is behind `?` (only console representation) can be very tedious.

[`detox`](http://detox.sourceforge.net/) will clean your filenames easily.

Comment: detox did it!!!! Thanks @GillesQuenot  !!!

Comment: I'm new in StackExchange... do I have to mark the cuestion as "SOLVED" or something like that??

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all `?` by `_` using the following loop:

```
for i in *
do
    echo "$i" | grep -q '?' && mv "$i" "${i//\?/_}"
done
```

I think I have finally figured it out and tested it.  I extracted all the files with control characters and non-ASCII characters and in a second loop, replaced the non-ASCII characters with `_`.

```
files=$(for i in *
        do
            echo "$i" | LANG="" sed -n '/[\x00-\x20]/p
                                        /[\x80-\xFF]/p'
        done)
for i in $files
do
    mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | LANG="" sed 's/[\x00-\x20]/_/g
                                       s/[\x80-\xFF]/_/g')"
done
```

Comment: Already tried... didn´t work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Then, your character `?` is something else. I guess the comments after your question verify that.

Comment: didn't work; I get a large list of erros saing that files or folders doesn't exist; for example: for a file called "2010 PLANILLA PARA RENDICIONES N? 5 10-12-2010-CORREGIDA.xls" I get the following errors:

Comment: mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'PLANILLA': No existe el fichero o el directorio
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'PARA': No existe el fichero o el directorio
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'RENDICIONES': No existe el fichero o el directorio
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre 'N'$'\272': No existe el fichero o el directorio
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre '5': No existe el fichero o el directorio
mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre '10-12-2010-CORREGIDA.xls': No existe el fichero o el directorio

Comment: Looks like you have spaces in file names.  If you remove the first loop and substitute `$files` with `*` in the second, it will work but give you error on the files that do not contain the non-ASCII characters.  Those files will not be changed anyway as source and destination will be the same.